# Заполнение RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Хочу вести логирование в RichTextBox, но при длительных операциях форма зависает.

Пробовал в отдельной задаче вызывать, но вылетает ошибка, что обращение к RichTextBox из другого потока не возможен.

Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: А как применяли поток? У меня есть пример на VB.Net с выводом лога в textbox при помощи таймера. Нужно?

Comment: Я на кнопку повесил вызов таскфэктори, которому кинул метод, а в конце вызвал wait.

Comment: Приведите кусок кода и текст ошибки. Как-то как базу использовала это решение -http://www.vedu.ru/programming/?cont=articles&articles_id=1100

Comment: элементы UI не любят работать с другими потоками. Вам нужен посредник, находящийся в потоке UI и принимающий сообщения от других потоков.

Comment: @rdorn, а можно примеры? Сценарий такой, есть кнопка, которая вызывает метод, который что-то долго делает и пишет в UI.

Comment: вот прям под ваш сценарий у микрософта пример есть, второй по ссылке в ответе

Comment: второй пример с BacgroundWorker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементы UI не любят работать с другими потоками, да и не должны. Поэтому нужно либо использовать готовые компоненты для реализации межпоточного взаимодействия, либо реализовать его явно.

Не вижу глубокого смысла копипастить официальную документацию по готовым компонентам, примеры кода смотри по ссылкам. Все ссылки на MSDN.

**1. Родное решение для WinForms** - использовать компонент `BackgroundWorker`: [описание](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), [примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7), [туториал](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx)

**2. Также можно использовать Dispatcher**, даже не смотря на то, что он относится к WPF. [Описание](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Выбор варианта - на мой взгляд дело вкуса, но у меня в этом не слишком большой практический опыт, возможно ошибаюсь.

**3. BeginInvoke** еще один вариант обращения к методам между потоками. В коде будет выглядеть так:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Run(new Action(TestThreading));
        AddText("Same thread");
    }

    void TestThreading()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        AddText("Async change");
    }

    public void AddText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<string> updaterdelegate = new Action<string>(AddText);
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(updaterdelegate, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) { }
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

идея [отсюда](http://usanov.net/792-multipotochnost-v-windowsforms-i-wpf), но там есть ошибка которая у меня уже исправлена, можно копипастить, не забыв кинуть на форму `TextBox`, будет также работать с любыми другими UI элементами и любыми их свойствами. Но если потоков много, не забудьте расставить блокировки на запись.

Comment: @rdom, а в 3 примере ничего дополнительно не нужно делать? Повесил на кнопку 'Task.Run(() => excl.Create());' и поток сразу же завершается. Нужно, наверное, что-то повесить на кнопку,что бы дожидаться завершения потока?

Comment: А зачем? UI по идее не должен ни кого ждать. Поток задачи это одно, поток UI - другое. Единственное что стоит сделать - на форму повесить ожидание завершения дочерних потоков или принудительное их завершение при закрытии

Comment: @rdom, а как правильно сделать так, что бы задача не "умерала" при выходе из кнопки, где эта задача создается?

Comment: @rdom, наверное, стоит создать какой-нибудь List<>, который будет хранить задачи?

Comment: @iluxa1810 это лучше отдельным вопросом оформить. Да и мне до компа добраться надо, с телефона только читать удобно

Comment: @rdom,http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548160/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5