# Как управлять потоками на форме?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tpl

Можно ли повесить создание задачи на кнопку, так что бы она не завершалась при выходе из кнопки или обязательно нужно хранить задачи в каком-нибудь списке?

Сценарий:

Нажимаю на кнопку, создается фоновая долгая задача, которая не прерывает UI.

Если делать так:

```
     private void btnToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
btnToExcel.Enabled = false;
                var excl=new ExcelCreator(tbConvDbPath.Text, tbPathToExcel.Text, AddText);
                taskList.Add(Task.Run(()=> excl.Create()));
btnToExcel.Enabled = true;//После завершения задачи
            }
```

То в методе выполняется только 1 инструкция...

Comment: "выполняется только 1 инструкция" Объедините  нужные вам инструкции в блок с помощью {}

Comment: @3per, в методе excl.Create() выполняется только 1 инструкция...

Comment: замените excl.Create()  на {excl.Create() ; следущая_инстукция;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Внимание! Ответ является не совсем удачным, в своё время не до конца понял автора, но ответ принят. Посмотрите лучше ответ от @andreycha*

```
private void btnToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnToExcel.Enabled = false;
    var excl=new ExcelCreator(tbConvDbPath.Text, tbPathToExcel.Text, AddText);
    taskList.Add(Task.Run(()=>
      {
         excl.Create();
         btnToExcel.Invoke(new Action
              (() =>
              {
                  btnToExcel.Enabled = true;//После завершения задачи
              }
      }));

}
```

Comment: Вопрос, а как сделать, что бы исключение в потоке видел основной поток?

Comment: например, прекратить основной поток.

Comment: 3per, странно, а у меня нет. Я пробовал явно в начале внутри excl.Create() вызывать throw new Exception и основному потоку пофиг, хотя никаких try/cath я не ставил.

Comment: возможно Task перехватывает исключение и не пробрасывает в основной поток.

Comment: @iluxa1810, возможно Вам стОит окончательно уточнить вопрос и снять галку с моего ответа?

Comment: Модератор не может взять и снять галочку, а удалять в данном случае - не вполне корректно. Зато хорошим вариантом может быть некоторое сообщение в начале вопроса: "Внимание, ответ не вполне соответствует вопросу потому-то и потому-то...". Обычно такие сообщения выделяют блоком цитаты, чтобы лучше видно было.

Answer (score 2):

Самый естественный вариант -- воспользоваться `async/await`:

```
private async void btnToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnToExcel.Enabled = false;

    var excl = new ExcelCreator(tbConvDbPath.Text, tbPathToExcel.Text, AddText);
    var task = Task.Run(() => excl.Create());
    taskList.Add(task);

    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ваша логика обработки исключения
    }
    finally
    {
        btnToExcel.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

P.S. Кстати, зачем вам `taskList`? Что вы с ним потом делаете?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь пулом потоков:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => "Ваш код", 5);
```

просто добавьте вашу задачу и она будет выполняться в фоновом потоке

Comment: А List с задачами все рано лучше оставить?

Comment: Если Вам нужен результат их выполнения или контроль выполнения, то лучше использовать механизм Task, а если нет, то список не нужен. Т.е. если у вас задача "запустил-забыл", то список не нужен

Comment: А можно пример в рамках сценария, который я описал выше? Или вообще поправить код, который я привел в примере?

Comment: А лучше еще вот так: При нажатии на кнопку, кнопка переводится в Enabled=false, а при завершении задачи в Enabled=true

Comment: только надо учесть, что кнопка может принадлежать другому потоку, поэтому используйте this.Invoke