# C#, parallel loop, output to richtextbox

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, tpl, plinq

Есть код:

```
string oa = "";
Parallel.ForEach(richTextBox1.Lines, async item =>
{
    oa = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
       () => Wor.SomeLongOperation(item),
       TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
       +"\n";
    richTextBox2.AppendText(oa);
});
```

У нас "многопоточность", из-за которой происходит конфликт потоков в записи в `rich` в этой строке `richTextBox2.AppendText(oa);`
Как можно сделать так, чтобы сохранить "многопоточность", но всё же результаты записывались в `rich`?

Comment: Мне на что-то похожее отвечали: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547493/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-richtextbox

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное. `Parallel.ForEach` и асинхронные методы не дружат.

Comment: мне нужна многопоточность, но при этом чтоб форма не зависала, Павел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что тело функции, которую вы передаете в `Parallel.ForEach()` выполняется в других потоках. Внутри этой функции вы обращаетесь к UI-компоненту. Но UI-компоненты позволяют с работать с собой [только в том же потоке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/), в котором они были созданы. Используя проверку `IsInvokeRequired` и вызов `Invoke()`, вы "перенаправляете" обращение к компоненту в главный (UI) поток и таким образом решаете проблему.

---

Кроме того, как указали в комментариях, у вас в коде "масло масляное". Дело в том, что вызов `Task.Factory.StartNew()` выполняет переданную ему функцию в отдельном потоке. Однако этот вызов *уже происходит в отдельном потоке*, поскольку вы используете `Parallel.ForEach()`. К этому добавляется еще проблема обработки исключений: делегат, который вы передаете в `Parallel.ForEach()` представляет собой `async void` и опасен тем, что вы либо не узнаете о возникшем исключении, либо узнаете, но будет поздно -- процесс упадет.

Нужно либо убрать вызов `Task.Factory.StartNew()` (внешняя переменная вам при этом тоже не нужна):

```
Parallel.ForEach(richTextBox1.Lines, item =>
{
    var oa = Wor.SomeLongOperation(item) + "\n";
    // вызов richTextBox2.AppendText(oa) через Invoke
});
```

Либо убрать `Parallel.ForEach()` (этот вариант будет работать медленнее, потому что мы выполняем долгую операцию в другом потоке одну за другой, а не сразу пачкой, как это происходит в случае с `Parallel.ForEach()`):

```
foreach (var item in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    var oa = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => Wor.SomeLongOperation(item),
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
        +"\n";
    richTextBox2.AppendText(oa);
};
```

Также для подобного кода как правило принято разделять шаг "делаем что-то в отдельном потоке" и шаг "выводим результат на UI". Например, если пользоваться async/await, на помощь придет класс [`Progress<T>`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/106).

Comment: К сожалению, это еще не ответ - первый способ все так же будет выдавать сообщение об ошибке, а второй способ будет работать последовательно (видимо, моя вина - сбил вас с толку своим комментарием).

Comment: В первом способе надо добавить `Invoke` - а во втором лучше использовать что-то вроде `await Task.WhenAll(richTextBox1.Lines.Select(async ... ));`

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, понятно, что во втором случае лучше `Task.WhenAll()`, однако я решил не грузить автора.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, дописываю с помощью функции:

```
 public void AddText(string text)
    {
        if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<string> updaterdelegate = new Action<string>(AddText);
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(updaterdelegate, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) { }
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox2.Text += text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Слишком сложно. Есть способы проще.